# Is this series convergent or not? Help

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{k-1}\ \frac{1\cdot4\cdots(3k-2)}{2\cdot5 \cdots(3k-1)}$

Is this series convergent or not?

I tried to apply alternating series tes but i could not calculate the limit of $\frac{1\cdot4\cdots(3k-2)}{2\cdot5 \cdots(3k-1)}$

I also tried to take logarithm but i could not end the process. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $e^{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log (1-\frac{1}{3k})}$. For small $x \approx 0 \  \log (1-x) < -x$, therefore 
$$
e^{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log (1-\frac{1}{3k})} < e^{-\frac{1}{3} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}} \sim n^{-\frac{1}{3}} \to 0 
$$
using Harmonic series. It is also monotone because $e^{-x}$ is strictly decreasing.

Now apply the alternating sign test.

Comment: Is it always the case that equiconvergent sequences  have the same monotonicity

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let $a_n$ be the general term.

$$\frac{|a_{n}|}{|a_{n+1}|}=\frac{3n+2}{3n+1}$$

$$=1+\frac{1}{3n+1}$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}n(\frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}-1)=\frac 13$$

Si, by Duhamel-Raab criteria, the series is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Decreasing, but not to zero, would show divergence.  Decreasing to zero would show convergence.  So I think this hint is not very helpful.

Comment: But the question is about conditional convergence.